# JAVA: gathering byte offsets of xml tags using an XmlStreamReader

Tags: java, xml, stax

Is there a way to accurately gather the byte offsets of xml tags using the XMLStreamReader?

I have a large xml file that I require random access to. Rather than writing the whole thing to a database, I would like to run through it once with an XMLStreamReader to gather the byte offsets of significant tags, and then be able to use a RandomAccessFile to retrieve the tag content later.

XMLStreamReader doesn't seem to have a way to track character offsets. Instead people recommend attaching the XmlStreamReader to a reader that tracks how many bytes have been read (the CountingInputStream provided by *apache.commons.io*, for example)

e.g:

```
CountingInputStream countingReader = new CountingInputStream(new FileInputStream(xmlFile)) ;
XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlStreamFactory.createXMLStreamReader(countingReader, "UTF-8") ;


while (xmlStreamReader.hasNext()) {
    int eventCode = xmlStreamReader.next();

    switch (eventCode) {
        case XMLStreamReader.END_ELEMENT :
            System.out.println(xmlStreamReader.getLocalName() + " @" + countingReader.getByteCount()) ;
    }

}
xmlStreamReader.close();
```

Unfortunately there must be some buffering going on, because the above code prints out the same byte offsets for several tags. Is there a more accurate way of tracking byte offsets in xml files (ideally without resorting to abandoning proper xml parsing)?

Comment: I've found the StAX2 API provides the very promising *LocationInfo* class, with the methods *getStartingByteOffset()* and *getStartingByteOffset()*. Unfortunately these always return -1. Is anyone familiar with Stax2 and Woodstox? Is there any way to configure the reader to make this location info available?

Comment: Dave: unfortunately with current implementation getting to actual byte offsets can not be done, even if parser is constructed straight from InputStream. So your best bet would be to use a Reader and character offsets: these are reliable and work.
This may incur extra costs but is more reliable than trying to use external solutions, where the problem is buffering of parser which makes it rather difficult to exact offsets.

Btw: Aalto would be able to give offsets, but it is bit less tested and has less functionality. But it does implement basic Stax completely.

Comment: Btw, feel free to ask this on Woodstox user or dev lists; others may have alternative suggestions. I do know that characters offsets are used in many places (for editors etc to indicate error locations for example)

Answer (score 2):

You could use getLocation() on the XMLStreamReader (or XMLEvent.getLocation() if you use XMLEventReader), but I remember reading somewhere that it is not reliable and precise.  And it looks like it gives the endpoint of the tag, not the starting location.

I have a similar need to precisely know the location of tags within a file, and I'm looking at other parsers to see if there is one that guarantees to give the necessary level of location precision.

Comment: This comes close, and I could handle getting the end of the tag rather than the start. The big problem is that it returns character offsets rather than byte offsets. My data is encoded in utf8 (variable length encoding) so there is no clean way to get byte offsets from this. >.<

Comment: The documentation for Location.getCharacterOffset()  says "If the input source is a file or a byte stream then this is the byte offset into that stream, but if the input source is a character media then the offset is the character offset."

So maybe it is possible to construct and chain the streams so it actually will give you a byte offset.  I'm thinking of something like feeding a file input stream into a byte array stream into the XML event stream?

Comment: That is starting to sound very dodgy, but good luck! I've officially given up and will simply store the content of the xml file in an indexed database (the idea was to have accurate byte offsets so that I could use a RandomAccessFile to read the parts of the xml file I needed, but that no longer seems like a good idea.

Comment: Actually, I think @Gigatron was extremely close to a solution in his comment. Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974196/xmlstreamreader-get-character-offset-xml-from-file, you can control whether getCharacterOffset() is a byte offset or character offset by what you pass to createXMLStreamReader(). For byte offset pass a Stream, for char offset pass a Reader. This only works for up to 2GB files though (maybe 4GB with some hacks), due to the int return value.

Comment: I know this is an old trail, but I would like to confirm what has been said: I have been using the Location object to get the character offset on a character media for a >50MB file, and it sometimes gives an incorrect character offset. Most of the time, it extracts the whole tag content, but it happens that it skips a few characters, and not on the same tags when I repeat the same operation, which lets me think of an implementation issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a wrapper input stream around the actual input stream, simply deferring to the wrapped stream for actual I/O operations but keeping an internal counting mechanism with assorted code to retrieve current offset?

Comment: I didn't follow that exactly, but the CountingInputStream is just a wrapper around an unbuffered InputStream, that keeps a count of how many bytes has been read. It sounds like I'm already doing what you suggest?

The problem is that the XMLStreamReader seems to be reading ahead and buffering somewhat. Say a there is an end tag 500 bytes into the file. The XMLStreamReader might fire the endElement event after reading 500 characters, or 501, or 600, whatever.

Comment: Yes you are right, not thinking properly. Anyway there is a getLocation() method in the interface which may work for you (if the parser supports proper Location objects). 
http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getLocation()
In turn Location offers: getCharacterOffset()

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly Aalto doesn't implement the LocationInfo interface.

The last java VTD-XML ximpleware implementation, currently 2.11
on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vtd-xml/files/vtd-xml/) or on [github](https://github.com/dryade/vtd-xml)
provides some code maintaning a byte offset after each call to
the getChar() method of its IReader implementations.

IReader implementations for various caracter encodings
are available inside VTDGen.java and VTDGenHuge.java

IReader implementations are provided for the following encodings

```
ASCII;
ISO_8859_1
ISO_8859_10
ISO_8859_11
ISO_8859_12
ISO_8859_13
ISO_8859_14
ISO_8859_15
ISO_8859_16
ISO_8859_2
ISO_8859_3
ISO_8859_4
ISO_8859_5
ISO_8859_6
ISO_8859_7
ISO_8859_8
ISO_8859_9
UTF_16BE
UTF_16LE
UTF8;   
WIN_1250
WIN_1251
WIN_1252
WIN_1253
WIN_1254
WIN_1255
WIN_1256
WIN_1257
WIN_1258
```

Updating IReader with a getCharOffset() method
and implementing it
by adding a charCount member along to the offset member of the
VTDGen and VTDGenHuge classes
and by incrementing it upon each getChar() and skipChar() call of each IReader implementation should give you the start of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found another option. If you replace your `switch` block with the following, it will dump the position immediately after the end element tag.

```
        switch (eventCode) {
        case XMLStreamReader.END_ELEMENT :
            System.out.println(xmlStreamReader.getLocalName() + " end@" + xmlStreamReader.getLocation().getCharacterOffset()) ;
        }
```

This solution also would require that the actual start position of the end tags would have to be manually calculated, and would have the advantage of not needing an external JAR file.

I was not able to track down some minor inconsistencies in the data management (I think it has to do with how I initialized my `XMLStreamReader`), but I always saw a consistent increase in the location as the reader moved through the content.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, this comes close, except that it returns character offsets rather than byte offsets. My data is encoded in utf8--variable length encoding--so there is no clean way to get byte offsets from this. >.<

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked out a solution for a similar question on [How to find character offsets in big XML files using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366566). I think it provides a good solution based on a ANTLR generated XML-Parser.

Answer (score 0):

I just burned a <s>day</s> long weekend on this, and arrived at the solution partially thanks to some clues here. Remarkably I don't think this has gotten much easier in the 10 years since the OP posted this question.

<s>TL;DR Use [Woodstox](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox) and char offsets</s>

The first problem to contend with is that most XMLStreamReader implementations seem to provide inaccurate results when you ask them for their current offsets. [Woodstox](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox) however seems to be rock-solid in this regard.

The second problem is the actual type of offset you use. Unfortunately it seems that you have to use char offsets if you need to work with a multi-byte charset, which means the random-access retrieval from the file is not going to be very efficient - you can't just set a pointer into the file at your offset and start reading, you have to read through until you get to the offset, then start extracting. <s>There may be a more efficient way to do this that I haven't though of, but the performance is acceptable for my case. 500MB files are pretty snappy.</s>

[edit] So this turned into one of those splinter-in-my-mind things, and I ended up writing a FilterReader that keeps a buffer of byte offset to char offset mappings as the file is read. When we need to get the byte offset, we first ask Woodstox for the char offset, then get the custom reader to tell us the actual byte offset for the char offset. We can get the byte offset from the beginning and end of the element, giving us what we need to go in and surgically extract the element from the file by opening it as a RandomAccessFile.

I created a library for this, it's on [GitHub](https://github.com/ThirdpartyLabs/XMLScalpel) and [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.thirdpartylabs/xmlscalpel-core). If you just want to get the important bits, the party trick is in the [ByteTrackingReader](https://github.com/ThirdpartyLabs/XMLScalpel/blob/main/src/main/java/com/thirdpartylabs/xmlscalpel/io/reader/ByteTrackingReader.java).
[/edit]

There is [another similar question on SO about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366566/using-stax-to-create-index-for-xml-for-quick-access) (but the accepted answer frightened and confused me), and some people commented about how this whole thing is a bad idea and why would you want to do it? XML is a transport mechanism, you should just import it to a DB and work with the data with more appropriate tools. For most cases this is true, but if you're building applications or integrations that communicate via XML (still going strong in 2020), you need tooling to analyze and operate on the files that are exchanged. I get daily requests to verify feed contents, having the ability to quickly extract a specific set of items from a massive file and verify not only the contents, but the format itself is essential.

Anyhow, hopefully this can save someone a few hours, or at least get them closer to a solution. God help you if you're finding this in 2030, trying to solve the same problem.