# Capture byte number/offset for SAXParser

Tags: java, xml, eclipse-plugin, sax, saxparser

Like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507350/java-xml-parsing-and-original-byte-offsets) I am trying to record the exact position when parsing XML.

I already use the SAX `Locator` passed to `setDocumentLocator()` to record the line and column number but that doesn't give the offset from the beginning of the file. Is there a way to find the number of bytes read so far by the SAX parser or offset of each line without re-reading the whole file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [another question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176610/java-gathering-byte-offsets-of-xml-tags-using-an-xmlstreamreader/3176965#3176965) which suggests using an XMLStreamReader instead of SAXParser because it has `getLocation().getCharacterOffset()` instead. It already has exactly what I need.

Comment: This is not correct.This way you get CHARACTER offset not BYTE offset. If your XML file contains at least one double byte character then you are in big trouble.

Comment: Please consider to take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366566

Answer (score 1):

Hypothetically, you can use the CountingInputStream from Apache commons IO.

Comment: Thanks. The input stream cannot be accessed from within my DefaultHandler descendent, right? That means I'll need to retain some other reference to it..?

Comment: This is a good answer but CountingInputStream isn't reliable enough.