# XMLStreamReader: get character offset : XML from file

Tags: java, stax

The `XMLStreamReader`->Location has a method called `getCharacterOffset()`.

Unfortunately the Javadocs indicate this is an ambigously named method: it can also return a byte-offset (and this appears to be true in practice); unhelpfully this seems to occur when reading from files (for instance):

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/Location.html#getCharacterOffset) states :

> Return the byte or character offset into the input source this
>   location is pointing to. If the input source is a file or a byte
>   stream then this is the byte offset into that stream, but if the input
>   source is a **character media** then the offset is the character offset. (emphasis added)

I really need the **character** offset; and I'm pretty sure I'm being given the **byte** offset instead.

The (UTF-8 encoded) XML is contained in a (partially corrupt 1G) file. [Hence the need to use a lower-level API which doesn't complain about the lack of well-formedness until it really has no choice but to].

**Question**

What does the Javadoc mean when it says '...input source is a character media...' : how can I force it to think of my input file as 'character media' - so that I get an accurate (Character) offset rather than a byte offset?

**Extra** blah blah:

[ I'm pretty sure this is what is going on - when I strip the file apart (using certain known high-level tags) I get a few characters missing or extra - in a non-accumalating way - I'm putting the difference down to a few multi-byte characters throwing off the counter: also when I copy (using 'head'/'tail' for instance in Powershell - this tool appears to correctly recognize [or assume UTF-8] and does a good conversion to UTF-16 as far as I can see ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offset is in units of the underlying `Source`.

The `XMLStreamReader` only knows how many units it has read from the `Source` so the offset is calculated in those units.

A `Stream` works in units of `byte` and therefore you end up with a `byte` offset.

A `Reader` works in units of `char` and therefore you end up with an offset in `char`.

The docs for [`StreamSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html) are more explicit in what the terms "character media" means.

Maybe try something like

```
final Source source = new StreamSource(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("my.xml")), "UTF-8"));
final XMLStreamReader xmlReader = XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamReader(source);
```

Answer (score 1):

`XMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(java.io.InputStream)` is a byte stream

`XMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(java.io.Reader)` is a character stream

Comment: When working with a byte stream ( XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(...)) ), is it an issue that the return type of getCharacterOffset() is an int, but a file (in bytes) can be a long sized file, as per File.length(), which returns a long?